# Ansible - Region us-east-2a does not seem to be available for aws module boto.ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, boto

I am trying to create an EC2 instance using Ansible but it shows the following error:

**Region us-east-2a does not seem to be available for aws module boto.ec2. If the region definitely exists, you may need to upgrade boto or extend with endpoints_path.**

I have to say that I am using *Ansible version 2.3.1.0* and *Boto 2.480*.

The error is showed right after trying to create the security group:

```
---
  - name: Provision an EC2 Instance
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    tags: provisioning
    # Necessary Variables for creating/provisioning the EC2 Instance
    vars_files: 
      - variables.yml
      - aws_auth.yml
    # Task that will be used to Launch/Create an EC2 Instance
    tasks:
      -   name: Create security group
              ec2_group:
              name: "{{ project_name }}_security_group"
              description: "{{ project_name }} security group"
              region: "{{ aws_region }}"
          rules:
              - proto: tcp
                type: ssh
                from_port: 22
                to_port: 22
                cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
              - proto: tcp
                type: http
                from_port: 80
                to_port: 80
                cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
              - proto: tcp
                type: https
                from_port: 443
                to_port: 443
                cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
          rules_egress:
              - proto: all
                type: all
                cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
      register: basic_firewall
```

The access key and the secret key are exported properly. I can run /etc/ansible/ec2.py --list and shows all the expected data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`us-east-2a` is not a **region**, it's an **availability zone**.  The region is called `us-east-2`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes you are right. It worked with us-east-2. Now I have a permissions problem ... :D. I can't create a security group. But I will see what I can do. It's a lot of documentation that needs to assimilated, and I have to do this in a couple of days. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue while working with ansible (2.9.6) and the [rds](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/rds_module.html) module:

```
- name: register db_facts
  rds:
    command: facts
    aws_access_key: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
    aws_secret_key: "AWS_SECRET_KEY"
    aws_region: "AWS_REGION_KEY"
    instance_name: "NAME_OF_RDS_INSTANCE"
  register: db_facts
```

The issue was that I was provisioning an Ubuntu 16.04 instance and the `python-boto` package. The available boto library was old so it didn't have the required region as I could confirm using the python:

```
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> for i in boto.ec2.regions():
...   print(i)
...
RegionInfo:us-east-1
RegionInfo:cn-north-1
RegionInfo:ap-northeast-1
RegionInfo:eu-west-1
RegionInfo:ap-southeast-1
RegionInfo:ap-southeast-2
RegionInfo:us-west-2
RegionInfo:us-gov-west-1
RegionInfo:us-west-1
RegionInfo:eu-central-1
RegionInfo:sa-east-1
```

I installed the updated version of the library to fix the issue:

```
pip install boto --upgrade
```

Here is the result of upgrading the library:

```
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> for i in boto.ec2.regions():
...   print(i)
...
RegionInfo:us-west-1
RegionInfo:us-east-1
RegionInfo:ap-northeast-1
RegionInfo:ap-southeast-2
RegionInfo:sa-east-1
RegionInfo:ap-northeast-2
RegionInfo:us-east-2
RegionInfo:ap-southeast-1
RegionInfo:ca-central-1
RegionInfo:cn-north-1
RegionInfo:us-west-2
RegionInfo:us-gov-west-1
RegionInfo:ap-south-1
RegionInfo:eu-central-1
RegionInfo:eu-west-1
RegionInfo:eu-west-2
```